# Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $

Tags: trigonometry

It is known that
\begin{align}
\arcsin x + \arcsin y  =\begin{cases}
\arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \\\quad\text{if } x^2+y^2 \le 1 &\text{or} &(x^2+y^2 > 1 &\text{and} &xy< 0);\\
\pi - \arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \\\quad\text{if } x^2+y^2 > 1&\text{and} &0< x,y \le 1;\\
-\pi - \arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \\\quad\text{if } x^2+y^2 > 1&\text{and} &-1\le x,y < 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I tried to prove this myself, have no problem in getting the 'crux' $\arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2})$ part of the RHS, but face trouble in checking the range of that 'crux' under the given conditions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), $\displaystyle-\frac\pi2\leq \arcsin z\le\frac\pi2 $ for $-1\le z\le1$

So, $\displaystyle-\pi\le\arcsin x+\arcsin y\le\pi$

Again, $\displaystyle\arcsin x+\arcsin y= 
\begin{cases} 
\\-\pi- \arcsin(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2})& \mbox{if } -\pi\le\arcsin x+\arcsin y<-\frac\pi2\\
\arcsin(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}) &\mbox{if } -\frac\pi2\le\arcsin x+\arcsin y\le\frac\pi2 \\ 
\pi- \arcsin(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2})& \mbox{if }\frac\pi2<\arcsin x+\arcsin y\le\pi \end{cases} $

and as like other trigonometric ratios are $\ge0$ for the angles in $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$

So, $\displaystyle\arcsin z\begin{cases}\text{lies in } \left[0,\frac\pi2\right] &\mbox{if } z\ge0 \\ 
\text{lies in } \left[-\frac\pi2,0\right] & \mbox{if } z<0  \end{cases} $

**Case** $(i):$
Observe that if $\displaystyle x\cdot y<0\ \ \ \ (1)$ i.e., $x,y$ are of opposite sign, $\displaystyle -\frac\pi2\le\arcsin x+\arcsin y\le\frac\pi2$

**Case** $(ii):$
If $x>0,y>0$   $\displaystyle \arcsin x+\arcsin y$ will be $\displaystyle \le\frac\pi2$ according as 
$\displaystyle \arcsin x\le\frac\pi2-\arcsin y$

But as $\displaystyle\arcsin y+\arccos y=\frac\pi2,$ we need $\displaystyle  \arcsin x\le\arccos y$

Again as the principal value of inverse cosine ratio lies in $\in[0,\pi],$
$\displaystyle\arccos y=\arcsin(+\sqrt{1-y^2})\implies \arcsin x\le\arcsin\sqrt{1-y^2}$

Now as sine ratio is increasing in $\displaystyle \left[0,\frac\pi2\right],$ we need $\displaystyle x\le\sqrt{1-y^2}\iff x^2\le1-y^2$ as $x,y>0$

$\displaystyle\implies x^2+y^2\le1 \ \ \ \ (2)$

So, $(1),(2)$ are the required condition  for $\displaystyle \arcsin x+\arcsin y\le\frac\pi2$

**Case** $(iii):$

Now as $\displaystyle-\frac\pi2\arcsin(-u)\le\frac\pi2 \iff -\frac\pi2\arcsin(u)\le\frac\pi2$

$\arcsin(-u)=-\arcsin u$

Use this fact to find the similar condition when $x<0,y<0$ setting $x=-X,y=-Y$

Comment: If there is any, I'll surely ask. I'll work it out myself first so that there is no scope of doubt. What I asked was just by going through your answer.

But I think it's pretty fine now. Thanks!

Comment: In the first case, by the condition $xy<0$ alone we have the proper range. That is, $\arcsin(x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Then why is that additional condition $x^2 + y^2 > 1$ required?

Comment: @ParthThakkar, its not required, the condition is either  $x^2+y^2\le1$ or ($xy<0$ where $x^2+y^2$ is obviously $>1$)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Wouldn't there be $\le$ sign in your first relation?

Comment: @user36790, The equality has been catered in the second

Comment: @labbhattacharjee How did you write when $x \gt 0$ and $y \gt 0$ $arcsin(x)+arc(siny) \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ for suppose when $x=1$ and $y=1$ $arcsin(x)+arc(siny)=\pi$ right? can you explain

Comment: @Umeshshankar, We also need $(1),(2)$

Comment: Ok fine when $xy \lt 0$ you said obviously $x^2+y^2 \gt 1$ i could not get this can you explain

Comment: @Umeshshankar, Which u r talking about?

Comment: I am talking about your reply to Parth thakkar in your first comment above

Comment: @Umesh, As it is the else case of $$x^2+y^2\le1$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee how to get the. conditions on a and y for the case $-\pi<\arcsin(x)+\arcsin(y)<-\pi/2$

Comment: @lindaOiladali, Have you identified for $$\dfrac\pi2<\arcsin x+\arcsin y<\pi$$  Then use $$\arcsin(-x)=-\arcsin x$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee i have the same question for $\pi/2<arcsin(x)+arcsin(y)<\pi$ how to get that $x^2+y^2>1$ and $0<x,y\leq1$

Comment: @lindaOiladali, If  $\arcsin x+\arcsin y>\dfrac\pi2; x,y$ must be $>0$


$$\iff\arcsin x>\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin y=\arccos(y)$$

Now for $y\ge0,$ $$\arccos(y)=\arcsin\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

So, we need $$\arcsin(x)>\arcsin\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

As $\arcsin(x)$ is increasing function, $$x>\sqrt{1-y^2}\implies x^2>1-y^2$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but if $x\leq 0$ and $y\leq 0$ we get the same thing no?

Comment: @lindaOiladali, If both $x,y\le0,$  $$\arcsin x+\arcsin y\le0$$  right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee right I understand, please in my exercise the question is "study according to a and b, the existence of solution for the equation arcsin(x)=arcsin(a)+arcsin(b), " so I must study only the case where $-\pi/2\leq arcsin(a)+arcsin(b)\leq\pi/2$ right?

Comment: Hi. In case (ii), when $x,y\gt0$, shouldn't $arcsin x+arcsin y$ be less than $\pi$, instead of $\frac\pi2$? Because $arcsin x\lt\frac\pi2$ and $\arcsin y\lt\frac\pi2$

Comment: @aarbee, I didn't say, it will be $<\dfrac\pi2$ but I wanted to check when that will be held true .

Answer (score 5):

Let $a=\sin^{-1}x,$ $b=\sin^{-1}y\implies\sin a=x,$ $\sin b=y$ and $a,b\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\implies a+b\in[-\pi,\pi]$
$$
\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b=x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\\=\sin\bigg[\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)\bigg]\\
\implies a+b=\color{red}{\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=n\pi+(-1)^n\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)}
$$
**Case 1:** $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
$$
\color{darkblue}{\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)}
$$
$$
\cos(a+b)\geq0\implies \cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b\geq0\implies \cos a\cos b\geq\sin a\sin b\\
\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\geq xy\implies\\
a)\ 1-x^2-y^2+x^2y^2-x^2y^2\geq0 \implies x^2+y^2\leq1\\
b)\ 1-x^2-y^2+x^2y^2-x^2y^2<0 \implies x^2+y^2>1, xy<0
$$
**Case 2 & 3:** $\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y\leq\pi$ and $-\pi\leq\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y<-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
$$
\cos(a+b)<0\implies x^2+y^2>1
$$

**Case 2-:** $\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y\leq\pi$
$$
\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)=\pi-(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y)\\
\implies \color{darkblue}{\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=\pi-\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)}
$$
$$
\dfrac{\pi}{2}<\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y\leq\pi \;\&\;-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}x,\;\sin^{-1}y\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
\implies 0<\sin^{-1}x,\sin^{-1}y\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}\implies 0< x,y\leq1
$$
**Case 3-:** $-\pi\leq\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y<-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$$
\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)=-\pi-(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y)\\
\implies \color{darkblue}{\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y=-\pi-\sin^{-1}\Big(x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)}
$$
$$
-\pi\leq\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y<-\dfrac{\pi}{2} \;\&\;-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}x,\;\sin^{-1}y\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
\implies -\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}x,\sin^{-1}y< 0\implies -1\leq x,y< 0
$$

Comment: why you consider cos(a+b)? @ss1729

Answer (score 2):

Take the sine of both sides, and use the [angle addition formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities), then further simplify it by using the fact that $\cos\arcsin t=\sqrt{\cos^2\arcsin t}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\arcsin t}=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. Then apply the $\arcsin$ function to both sides, and you're done.

Comment: As I have said in my question, I don't have any problem in getting the main part: $ \arcsin(x\sqrt{1-x^2} + y\sqrt{1-y^2}) $. I don't know how to do the range checking so that I can adjust the RHS with $\pi$.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: $\sin t=\sin(\pi-t)$. (Always picture the unit circle in your mind). And since $\pi$ and $-\pi$ are the same (again, visualize), QED.

Answer (score 2):

Hope the graph explains the x,y domain ( |x|< 1, |y|< 1 ) and range.

[image: Arcsinx,..&y]