# Two differentiation results of $\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Tags: calculus

While trying to differentiate $\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})$, if we put
$x = \sin\theta$, we get,

\begin{align*}
  y &=\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(2\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta})\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)\\
  &= 2\theta\\
  &= 2\sin^{-1}x.
\end{align*}

So,
\begin{align*}
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.\\
\end{align*}

But if we put $x = \cos\theta$, we get,

\begin{align*}
  y &=\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(2\cos\theta\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta})\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(2\cos\theta\sin\theta)\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)\\
  &= 2\theta\\
  &= 2\cos^{-1}x.
\end{align*}

This time,

\begin{align*}
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.\\
\end{align*}

We are perplexed about the difference in sign between the two results
and thought that you could help.

(We understand that we can differentiate $\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})$ directly, without any substitution, which gives us the first result.)

Comment: Hint: What is $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2\theta))$?

Comment: $2\theta$, somehow we fail to get the hint.

Comment: Another result for $\sin^{-1} \sin 2\theta$ is $\pi - 2\theta$, perhaps that is what you mean. But how do we decide which of the results to choose?

Comment: It is a complicated issue and you generally have to consider the values your $\theta$ takes on. You can see how the issue arises from both the fact that $\sin^{-1}$ is not a "true inverse" and from the fact that absolute value signs are easy to ignore. The short answer is that the result you will use depends on your substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $\sin^{-1}$ is not a "true inverse". Here is a graph of $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2x))$.

[image]

I think it is clear that this is the most likely source for your sign error. As you note, you could have a different choice for arcsin which would give you the opposite sign when differentiating.

I think the easiest way to reason into the first choice is that because $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is increasing your derivative should be positive.

If you wanted to be more precise, remember that you are only considering values of $x$ such that $-1 \leq 2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \leq 1$. If you let $x = \cos\theta$ you will use values of theta that are greater than $\pi/2$ because you need $x$ to be negative. If you let $x = \sin(\theta)$ you can let $\theta$ take on values between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ which is where $\sin^{-1}$ is "nicely defined".

After all of this, let me correct an error in your work. This is where the "paradox" arises.

For $x = \sin(\theta)$

\begin{align*}
  y &=\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(2\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta})\\
  &= \color{red}{\sin^{-1}(2\sin\theta|\cos\theta|)}\\
\end{align*}

For $x = \cos\theta$

\begin{align*}
  y &=\sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})\\
  &= \sin^{-1}(2\cos\theta\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta})\\
  &= \color{red}{\sin^{-1}(2\cos\theta|\sin\theta|)}\\
\end{align*}

If we chose $x = \sin(\theta)$ then $\theta$ is such that $\cos(\theta)$ is always positive and we don't need the absolute value signs and we can continue just as we did.

If we choose $x = \cos(\theta)$ then $\theta$ is such that $\sin(\theta)$ is always negative so here is the source of the discrepancy. A negative sign should be introduced after taking the square root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation. Like most of the other questions in this forum, this was for my son, who wants to know the reason behind anything.

Answer (score 0):

This Question bugged me for long time before I found the linked identity

Setting  $y=x$ in [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y),

$$
2\arcsin x\\
\begin{align}
&=\arcsin( 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;2x^2 \le 1  \\
&=\pi - \arcsin(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;2x^2 > 1\text{ and } 0< x\\
&=-\pi - \arcsin(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}) \;\;;2x^2 > 1\text{ and }  x\le 0\\
\end{align}
$$

**Case** $\#1:$ If $2x^2 \le 1,\arcsin( 2x\sqrt{1-x^2})=2\arcsin x$

**Case** $\#2:$  If $2x^2> 1,$

**Case** $\#2A: x>0,\arcsin( 2x\sqrt{1-x^2})=\pi-2\arcsin x=2\arccos x$

**Case** $\#2B: x\le0,\arcsin( 2x\sqrt{1-x^2})=-\pi-2\arcsin x$

Comment: @Masroor, How about this?