# Proving a trigonometric identity (involving arcos(x))

Tags: trigonometry

Not very familiar with how to do this problem. Not sure on the process 
of how to get the answer. Thanks for the help to those who help answer 
it! :)

Assuming all angles are acute, show that: $\cos ^{-1}x+\cos 
^{-1}y=\lbrack xy-\sqrt{\lbrace (1-x^{2})(1-y^{2}\rbrace }\rbrack $

Comment: do you mean $\arccos(x)+\arccos(y) = \arccos(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$

Comment: Take the cosine for the LHS and expand.

Comment: Use  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116974/why-its-true-arcsinx-arccosx-frac-pi2. and
   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: What  if $x=y=\dfrac12$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Compute the cosine of both sides. You'll need to calculate $\sin(\arccos x)$, which shouldn't be too hard, since you know all angles are acute.

Answer (score 0):

let $X =\arccos(x)\implies x=\cos(X)$

$ Y =\arccos(y)\implies y=\cos(Y)$

now;

$\cos(X+Y) = \cos(X)\cos(Y)-\sin(X)\sin(Y)$

$\cos(X+Y)= xy- \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}$

$X+Y=\arccos\bigg(xy- \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg) $

$\therefore\arccos(x)+\arccos(y) =\arccos\bigg(xy- \sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg)$