# Can neglecting the use of a definite integral property when it is very obvious yield incorrect answers?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I was analyzing this integral which prompted me to ask this question:
\begin{aligned}
& \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-\tan ^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan ^2 \frac{x}{2}}\right) d x \\
& \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos ^{-1}(\cos x) d x \\
& \int_0^{2 \pi} x d x=\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)_0^{2 \pi}=\frac{1}{2}\left(4 \pi^{-2}\right)=2 \pi^2 \\
& \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos ^{-1}(\cos (2 \pi-x))= 2*\int_0^\pi \cos ^{-1}(\cos x)=2 \int_0^\pi x=\pi^2
\end{aligned}

Why I'm I getting 2 different answers when used with (3rd step) and without (final step) the property? I'm neither sure whether it is due to some inverse trignometric property or due to my lack of understanding of definite integral properties.

Could someone please explain. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving Inverse trig problems using substitution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717604/solving-inverse-trig-problems-using-substitution) (the answer explains, among other things, why $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$ is not always equal to $x$)

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you. Yes