# How do I simplify this sum of arccosines?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, summation

After trying to solve a geometry problem, represented by the following image

[image]

I've arrived at this expression:

$\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{d+r \cos \left(\varphi+\frac{\vartheta}2\right)}{\sqrt{d^2+r^2+2 dr\cos \left(\varphi+\frac{\vartheta}2\right)}}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{d+r\cos \left(\varphi-\frac{\vartheta}2\right)}{\sqrt{d^2+r^2+2dr\cos\left(\varphi-\frac{\vartheta}2\right)}}\right)$

Is there a way to simplify such expression?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116974/why-its-true-arcsinx-arccosx-frac-pi2 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Answer (score 1):

$$\arccos \beta +\arccos \gamma=\arccos \left(\beta\cdot\gamma-\sqrt{1-\beta^2} \cdot \sqrt{1-\gamma^2}\right)$$

On Wikipedia there are also these identities:

$$\arccos x_1+\arccos x_2=
\begin{cases}
\arccos\left(x_1x_2-\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\sqrt{1-x_2^2}\right)&
x_1+x_2\ge0\\
2\pi-\arccos\left(x_1x_2-\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\sqrt{1-x_2^2}\right)&
x_1+x_2<0
\end{cases}
$$

$$\arccos x_1-\arccos x_2=
\begin{cases}
-\arccos\left(x_1x_2+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\sqrt{1-x_2^2}\right)&
x_1\ge x_2\\
\arccos\left(x_1x_2+\sqrt{1-x_1^2}\sqrt{1-x_2^2}\right)&
x_1<x_2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Nice. This comes from the angle addition formula (Let $\beta = \cos B$ and $\gamma = \cos C$.