# Solving trigonometric expressions in $x$

Tags: trigonometry

I am having problems understanding how to write an algebraic expression in $x$ for:

$$\sin\left(\arcsin(x)-\arctan\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(\arcsin(x) - \arctan(2/x)")"$

Comment: @JessePFrancis, if you see such mistakes next time in any question, you can use the edit option to suggest an edit.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, I know, in this case, $\sin(\arcsin(x)) - \arctan(2/x)$ is also possible.

Comment: @JessePFrancis, if that was the case, OP would've written $\sin(\arcsin(x))$ and not $\sin(\arcsin(x)$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $x\in(0,1)$, we have:
$$\sin\left(\arcsin x-\arctan\frac{2}{x}\right)= x\cdot\cos\arctan\frac{2}{x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}\cdot\sin\arctan\frac{2}{x}$$
by the sine addition formulas and the Pythagorean theorem in the form $\cos\arcsin x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Since:
$$\cos\arctan\frac{2}{x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}},\qquad \sin\arctan\frac{2}{x}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+x^2}},$$
it follows that:

> $$\sin\left(\arcsin x-\arctan\frac{2}{x}\right)=\frac{x^2-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\arctan\dfrac2x=y,\tan y=\dfrac2x,-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos y\ge0$

$\cos y=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\tan^2y}}=\cdots$

$\implies\sin y=\tan y\cdot\cos y=\cdots$

Now $\arcsin(-z)=-\arcsin(z)$

Finally use [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y)

Answer (score 0):

For arcs in the first quadrant, we can put:
$$
\arcsin x=\alpha \iff x=\sin \alpha \iff \cos \alpha=\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
$$
\arctan (2/x)= \beta \iff \tan \beta=2/x  
$$
so that:
$$
\cos \beta=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \beta}}=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}
$$

$$
\sin \beta=\dfrac{\tan \beta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \beta}}=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}
$$

Now using
$$
\sin (\alpha-\beta)= \sin \alpha \cos \beta-\cos \alpha \sin \beta
$$
and substituing you fine the result.

Comment: Ooops... some minute after @Jack.. (upvote!)