# What is connection here between $x$ and interval: $\sin^{-1}(2x(\sqrt{1-x^2})=2\sin^{-1}x$ .

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

For the expression

\begin{equation*}
 \sin^{-1}(2x(\sqrt{1-x^2})=2 \sin^{-1}x,~x\in[\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}],
\end{equation*}

I know there is a connection between the interval and the value of $x$, what is that connection and why we are taking a specific value of $x$ in this interval, and why the value of $x$ is changed with interval.

Comment: See  something more generic : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: Just carefully see for the domains and angle. You'd easily see the two idenities where once it's cos inverse and other is sine inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Try $x=\sin\theta$ where:
$$\arcsin\sin2\theta=2\arcsin\sin\theta$$ 
So $|2\theta|\le\pi/2$ and $|\theta|\le\pi/2$ due to domain restrictions (otherwise LHS becomes $\pm\pi/2-2\theta$ depending upon situation) and hence $|\theta|\le\pi/4\implies |\sin\theta|\le1/\sqrt2\implies |x|<1/\sqrt2$

Comment: @ADGif we take $x=cos^{-1}$?,then what'd happen.

Comment: @Sharma unclear what you want to say?

Comment: @Sharma why do you want to do that? what is the need of it? it'll make it $|\arccos x|<1\implies |x|>\cos 1$ and maybe some other minor changes too

Comment: @ADGif we substitue x=cosx  in above problem ,then it will define in this interval?

Comment: @ADGwe take x=sin  to prove above situation not cos  why?

Comment: @Sharma that'll make it a little longer and a little tedious