# Evaluating the inverse trigonometric limit $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\arccos \left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

> $$
> \lim_{x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\arccos \left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
> $$

I was doing some questions on limits, I saw one in which there is $\arccos x$. I am stuck there, not able to proceed.

Can you give me some hint?

Comment: when $x$ tends to $\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ from left we get $-\infty$ and when from right we get $+\infty$ and hence limit doesn't exist.

i mean **LHL$\ne$RHL**

Comment: @DeNiSkA  how can we say about LHL AND RHL

Comment: when i say $x$ tends to $\frac1{\sqrt2}$ i mean LHL and when i say from right i mean RHL, i hope this makes some sense!

Comment: @DeNiSkA but how can we say it is -∞ or +∞.

Comment: limit of $1/x$ doesn't exist at $x=0$ why because LHL$\ne$RHL, similarly as we know that numerator of your limit tends to a finite number and denominator tends to two different numbers so it doesn't exist

Comment: you many give me a counter example of $\sin x/x$ at $x=0$ but when denomiator tends to a negative number even numerator tends to negative number hence limit exists, is it making sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $$\arccos2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Now using [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y), $$2\arcsin x=\begin{cases}\arcsin2x\sqrt{1-x^2} &\mbox{if } |x|\le\dfrac1{\sqrt2} \\ \pi-\arcsin2x\sqrt{1-x^2}  & \mbox{if } x>\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\\-\pi-\arcsin2x\sqrt{1-x^2}  & \mbox{if } x<-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}
 \end{cases}$$

$$\implies\lim_{x\to\frac1{\sqrt2}^+}\frac{\arccos \left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=2\lim_{x\to\frac1{\sqrt2}^+}\frac{\arcsin x-\dfrac\pi4}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\dfrac{d(\arcsin x)}{dx}_{(\text{ at } x=\pi/4)}$$

and $$\lim_{x\to\frac1{\sqrt2}^-}\frac{\arccos \left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=-2\lim_{x\to\frac1{\sqrt2}^-}\frac{\arcsin x-\dfrac\pi4}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=?$$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764431/solving-arcsin-left2x-sqrt1-x2-right-2-arcsin-x

Answer (score 1):

Set $t=\arccos(2x\sqrt{1-x^2})$, so $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos t$ and, by definition, $0\le t\le\pi$. Then
$$
\sin t=\sqrt{1-\cos^2t}=\sqrt{1-4x^2+4x^4}=|2x^2-1|
$$
and so $t=\arcsin|2x^2-1|$. Thus your limit (from the right) can be written
$$
\lim_{x\to(1/\sqrt2)^+}\sqrt{2}\frac{\arcsin|2x^2-1|}{\sqrt{2}x-1}=
\lim_{x\to(1/\sqrt2)^+}\sqrt{2}
\frac{(\sqrt{2}x+1)\arcsin(2x^2-1)}{2x^2-1}
$$
which you should be able to compute.

Note then that, for $x<1/\sqrt{2}$, $|2x^2-1|=-(2x^2-1)$ and you can go similarly for the limit as $x\to(1/\sqrt{2})^-$

Answer (score -1):

That $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ shouts "Trigonometric functions!!!". So:

Put $x=\sin\theta$, which means that $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos\theta$. Then $$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\arccos \left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)}{x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\equiv \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\arccos \left(\sin 2\theta \right)}{\sin \theta-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\equiv \lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta}{\sin \theta-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

You can use l'Hôpital from here. Or...

Put $\phi=\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}$. The limit becomes $$\lim_{\phi \to 0} \frac{-2\phi}{\sin \phi \cos\frac{\pi}{4} + \cos \phi \sin\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \equiv \lim_{\phi \to 0} \frac{-2\phi}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sin \phi + \cos \phi -1)}$$

…which you can l'Hôpital again, or note that for small $\phi$, $\sin\phi$ is practically $\phi$ and $\cos\phi$ is practically 1, so that the limit becomes $$\frac{-2}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$$
…which I leave to you to work out. This is essentially reproducing what l'Hôpital does, but by doing it yourself you can actually see *what* you are doing.

Comment: I think the limit does not exist

Comment: Over the range in question it makes no difference.

Comment: when you use l'hopital rule it says limit doesn't exist so you can say nothing about original limit!

Comment: @akbar: if you are in doubt, get a calculator and work out the values of the expression for $(1/\sqrt 2)+0.1$, $(1/\sqrt 2)+0.01$, $(1/\sqrt 2)+0.001$. This is actually a very good way to "get the feel" of a question before solving it.

Comment: The usual definition of $\arccos$ only takes nonnegative values, so we cannot have $\arccos(\ast) = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2 \theta$ for $\theta > \frac{\pi}{4}$, as the r.h.s. is negative for such values.