# find radius, given 3 chords, measuring 3,2,1.

Tags: geometry

I have a semi-circumference.  There are three chords within it, one after the other. The chords measure 3, 2 and 1.  Find the radius of the semi-circumference.
Thanks.

Edit by DS:

[image]

Comment: as stated, the radius can be whichever $3 \le r$ . What do you mean by "..one after the other"?

Comment: Presumably you mean that is a semi circle, and the chords intersect on the circumference of the semicircle?

Comment: I understand this as: We have points $A,B,C,D$ on a circle (in this order), where $|AB|=3$, $|BC|=2$, $|CD|=1$ and $AD$ is a diameter.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you verify that the image I have added is a correct understanding of the problem ? ... Anyone can you redraw this image ... nicely ? ...

Comment: You need to show what you have done to try and solve this problem. MSE usually looks unfavorably upon questions where no demonstrated attempt at a solution has been made.

Comment: Did you know that the perpendicular bisector of a chord of a circle passes through the center of the circle?

Answer (score 2):

The length of a chord made in a circle radius $r$ by angle $\theta$  is $2r\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)$

So radius $r$ is the solution to $$2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{2r}\right) + 2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{2r}\right)+2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2r}\right) = \pi$$

There are apparently [ways of adding arcsines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y), but in any case numerically it seems $r \approx 2.056545292$.

I have no idea whether it is connected, but this is the positive root of $2r^3-7r-3=0$.

This diagram shows the chords in the semicircle

[image]