# Prove $\tan^{-1}m+\tan^{-1}n=\cos^{-1}\frac{1-mn}{\sqrt{1+m^2}\sqrt{1+n^2}}$ (part of sum)

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking for a specific clarification for a part of the solution in proving the following identity.
$\tan^{-1}m+\tan^{-1}n=\cos^{-1}\frac{1-mn}{\sqrt{1+m^2}\sqrt{1+n^2}}$

Here I'm taking, $\theta=\tan^{-1}m;$ $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$

so I get $\tan\theta=m$---(1)

I need to find $\sin \theta  $and  $\cos \theta$ in terms of m

By Trigonometric identity I can easily derive, $\cos \theta$

$\tan^2\theta+1=\sec^2\theta$

$\cos^2\theta=\frac{1}{m^2+1}$

$\cos\theta=+\sqrt\frac{1}{m^2+1}$ ( here only plus due to range of $\theta$)

Now if I deduce $\sin\theta$ from,

$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$

> I get, $\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt\frac{m^2}{m^2+1}$ ( I have to take $\pm$ because of range of $\theta$)

But if I deduce $\sin\theta$ from (1)

> I get, $\sin\theta=\frac{m}{\sqrt {m^2+1}}$

Which of the following method is correct to find $\sin\theta$? Please help me. Thank you!

P.S. I'm not interested in the solution. What I need to know is how to find $\sin\theta$

Comment: How did you get the positive sign for $\sin \theta $ using 1)?

Comment: since equation (1) means $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, I substituted the $cos\theta$value I obtained there.

Comment: You need appropriate restrictions on $m$ and $n$. For example, the formula is false in the case $m=-\surd3$ with $n=1/\surd3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

We need $\tan^{-1}m+\tan^{-1}n\ge0$  to admit the equality

$$\tan^{-1}m+\tan^{-1}n\ge0\iff\tan^{-1}m>-\tan^{-1}n=\tan^{-1}(-n)$$
$$\iff m\ge-n\iff m+n\ge0$$

Now use [Inverse trigonometric function identity doubt: $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y =-\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$, when $x<0$, $y<0$, and $xy>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837410/inverse-trigonometric-function-identity-doubt-tan-1x-tan-1y-pi-tan)

Then if $\tan^{-1}x=y,-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2,\cos y>0$

$x=\tan y\implies\cos y=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$\tan^{-1}x=\text{sign of}(x)\cdot\cos^{-1}\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

**See also** : [Proving that $\cos^{-1}\frac{4}{5}+\cos^{-1}\frac{12}{13}=\cos^{-1}\frac{33}{65}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628370/proving-that-cos-1-frac45-cos-1-frac1213-cos-1-frac3365)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have means to put up the image for my plot so bear with me.

Take a right-angled triangle $ABC$ such that AB is the height $=m$ and BC is the base $=1$. $\widehat{ABC}=90^\circ$ and $\widehat{ACB}=\tan^{-1} m$

Let $AC=y$. Draw a line $AE$ perpendicular to $AC$ at $A$ equal to $ny$. $\widehat{EAC}=90^\circ$ and $\widehat{ACE}=\tan^{-1} \dfrac{ny}{y}=\tan^{-1} n$. Additionally, let $EC=z$

Extend $AB$ past $A$. Draw a perpendicular from E to that line and name that intersection $D$. $\widehat{EAD}=\widehat{ACB}$. This is because of the right angle $\widehat{EAC}$. Hence $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle EDA$. This equality follows:

$\dfrac{AB}{AC}=\dfrac{ED}{EA}$

$\dfrac{m}{y}=\dfrac{ED}{ny}$

$ED=mn$

Draw a perpendicular to $BC$ at $C$ and extend $DE$ past $E$. Label the point where these lines meet as $F$. We have created a rectangle in $DBCF$, thus $DF=BC=1$:

$EF+DE=1$

$EF=1-mn$

Additionally, $DF \parallel BC$ hence $\widehat{ECB}=\widehat{CEF} \text{  Alternate angles}$

$\widehat{ECB}=\widehat{ACB}+\widehat{ECA}=\tan^{-1} m+\tan^{-1} n$

$\widehat{CEF}=\cos^{-1} \dfrac{EF}{EC}$

$\dfrac{EF}{EC}=\dfrac{1-mn}{z}$

Remember now all the right-angled triangles we drew.

$z^2=(ny)^2+y^2=y^2(n^2+1)$

$y^2=m^2+1$

$z^2=(n^2+1)(m^2+1)$

$z=\sqrt{(n^2+1)(m^2+1)}$

$\dfrac{EF}{EC}=\dfrac{1-mn}{\sqrt{(n^2+1)(m^2+1)}}$

$\widehat{CEF}=\cos^{-1} \dfrac{1-mn}{\sqrt{(n^2+1)(m^2+1)}}$

But $\widehat{ECB}=\widehat{CEF}$, hence:

$\boxed{\tan^{-1} m+\tan^{-1} n=\cos^{-1} \dfrac{1-mn}{\sqrt{(n^2+1)(m^2+1)}}}$

Edit: the formula kinda breaks down when $m$ and $n$ don't have the same sign i.e $n \lt 0 \lt m$ for example. But they won't be that different. For example, using $-\sqrt{3}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ yields $-30^\circ$ and $30^\circ$ on the left and right respectively. But they do have the same cosine value meaning they're not too distinct.

Comment: what if m is negative will your statement be correct length AB=m?( second statement of your proof)

Comment: Yes. Just flipped over. I think my diagram would extend for positive and negative acute angles, from which all other quadrants can follow.

Comment: And besides, if you check Wikipedia their proof of the sine addition formula is geometric, from which all other angles can follow. Also, if $m\ge \frac{1}{n}$, then $\tan^{-1}m + \tan^{-1} n \ge 90^\circ$ and $1 \le mn$, $1-mn \le 0$ which does correspond to the cosine of an obtuse angle.

Comment: Sorry as you pointed out the answer is what you have written.. I just now corrected it. But how can you address the sine issue?

Comment: It's completely correct. Both of them. It's just that the second one came immediately from a square root. That can be a problem sometimes. The best thing for that is to decide for yourself which quadrant you're working with and move on with it. Like the way I know mine is obviously in acute angles. But the determination is important. For example if you used that Pythagorean identity with a negative cosine to work out sine then the positive value is for the 2nd quadrant angle and the negative the 3rd and so on.

Comment: And I'm sorry for giving the solution you were not interested in.