# Is there any formula to find $\sin^{-1}a +\sin^{-1}b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We known that$$\tan^{-1} a  +\ tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a+b}{1-ab}\right).$$

Now we derive the above formula. Let$$
\tan^{-1}a=\theta _1 \implies \tan\theta_1=a,\\
\tan^{-1}b=\theta _2 \implies \tan\theta_2=b,\\
\theta _1+\theta _2 = \tan^{-1}a+ \tan^{-1}b,\\
\tan(\theta _1+\theta _2) = \tan(\tan^{-1}a+\tan^{-1}b)·
\tan(\theta _1+\theta _2)\\
=\frac{ \tan(\tan^{-1}a)+\tan( \tan^{-1}b)}{1- \tan(\tan^{-1}a)· \tan(\tan^{-1}b)},\\
(\theta _1+\theta _2) =\tan^{-1}\left(\frac {a+b}{1-ab}\right).
$$
Therefore, $\tan^{-1} a  +\ tan^{-1}b=\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{a+b}{1-ab}\right)$.

For all  $\theta _1$ and $\theta _2$ such that $0 \le \theta _1,\theta _2 \lt 90$, in the similar way I try to find  $\sin^{-1}a +\sin^{-1}b$. Let$$
\sin^{-1}a=\theta_1, \quad \sin^{-1}b=\theta_2,\\
\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\sin(\sin^{-1}a +\sin^{-1}b),\\
\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\sin(\sin^{-1}a)·\cos(sin^{-1}b) +\sin(\sin^{-1}b)·\cos(sin^{-1}a),\\
\theta_1+\theta_2=\sin(\sin^{-1}a)·\cos(sin^{-1}b) +\sin(\sin^{-1}b)·\cos(sin^{-1}a),\\
\sin^{-1}a+\sin^{-1}b=\sin(\sin^{-1}a).cos(sin^{-1}b) +\sin(\sin^{-1}b).cos(sin^{-1}a),\\
\sin^{-1}a+\sin^{-1}b=\sin(a)·\cos(\sin^{-1}b) +\sin(b)·\cos(\sin^{-1}a).$$
It cannot be write in the form only using $a$ and $b$.
$$\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A·\tan B}.$$ It contains only $\tan$ terms. But $\sin(A+B)=\sin A·\cos B+\cos A·\sin B$, which contains both $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms.

Is there any formula for $\sin^{-1}a+\sin^{-1}b$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$. Then, since$$\sin\left(\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)\right)=a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2},$$we have$$\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)=\arcsin\left(a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}\right).$$

Comment: What if $a=b=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ALPHA24 When $a=b=\frac12$, both $\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)$ and $\arcsin\left(a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)$ are equal to $\frac\pi3$.

Comment: @ALPHA24 If $a=b=\frac12$, then $\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)=\frac\pi6+\frac\pi6=\frac\pi3$ and$$\arcsin\left(a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)=\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)=\frac\pi3.$$Do you disagree?

Comment: No, I agree this