# Inverse trigonometric formula logic?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

[image]
[image]

What is the logic behind adding/subtracting pi in the above formulas? I have heard from people that graphs can help but I'm not sure how.

Comment: If you really must include pictures, please ensure they are all the right way up.

Comment: Apologies. Edited the question

Comment: As Range of the function $f(x)$=$arcsin$ $x$ is $[-π/2,π/2]$......also for $arccos$  ,etc

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y