# derivative of Inverse Trigonometric problems

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inverse, inverse-function

I am unable to understand why the derivative of : $$y = \sin^{-1}(2x\sqrt {1-x^2}), {-1\over\sqrt{2}}<x<{1\over\sqrt{2}} $$

is: $$  2\over\sqrt {1-x^2}  $$

and why it cannot be / is not :  $$  -2\over\sqrt {1-x^2}  $$

well, if we take $x$ as $\cos\theta$ and proceed...

$$ y = \sin^{-1}(2 \cos\theta\sqrt {1-\cos^2\theta}) $$

$$ \Rightarrow y =\sin^{-1}(2\sin\theta \cos\theta) $$

$$ \Rightarrow y = \sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)$$

$$ \Rightarrow y = 2\theta $$

$$ \Rightarrow y = 2\cos^{-1}x $$

the derivative comes out to be: $$  -2\over\sqrt {1-x^2}  $$

Now, at first, I thought that it's due to the domain inequality ${-1\over\sqrt{2}}<x<{1\over\sqrt{2}}$ (if we take the $\cos^{-1}$ of this inequality, we get an absurd solution. $({3\pi \over 4} < \cos^{-1}x < {\pi \over 4})$.

Certainly, ${3\pi \over 4} < {\pi \over 4}$ is False. So I thought this was the reason why we cant take $x$ as $\cos\theta$. ( we take $x$ as $\sin\theta$ and get the right answer $2\over\sqrt {1-x^2}$

Then, the next question was to find the derivative of:

$$ y = \sec^{-1}{1 \over (2x^2 - 1)} , 0<x<{1\over\sqrt{2}} $$

Here taking $x$ as $\cos\theta$ gives the absurdity again, BUT gives the answer too... So, after all, what is the correct way to solve these problems?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: When $x=\cos\theta$, the continuous branch of $y=\sin^{-1}\sin(2\theta)$ is not $2\theta$, but $\pi-2\theta$.  You can see this by trying $x=0$, so $\theta=\pi/2$ and $y=\sin^{-1}(\sin\pi)=0$.

Comment: $\sqrt {1-\cos^2 \theta} = \sqrt {\sin^2 \theta} = |\sin \theta|.$ In this case $-\frac {\pi} {4} < \theta < \frac {\pi} {4}.$ In this range of $\theta,$ $\sin \theta \not\geq 0.$ Therefore $|\sin \theta| \neq \sin \theta.$

Comment: Please share the details of the last absurdity

Comment: @labbhattacharjee to solve the second problem, when we put x as $cos\theta$ and then take the cos inverse, we get pi < pi/4 ....

Comment: @Dbchatto67 okay, so we are basically unsure about the sign of $sin\theta$ when we take x as $cos\theta$ and hence we put the mod function, so to counter that uncertainty, we simply take x as $ sin\theta$?

Comment: @JShelly, See my answer below: $x>0\implies \cos^{-1}x\le\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: Just a remark: For positive $x$ your function is obviously increasing (and then also for negative $x$, since it's an odd function), so the derivative cannot possibly be negative.

Answer (score 2):

Always keep in mind the principal values of

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

$-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}  <x<\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

actually implies $\dfrac{3\pi}4>\arccos x=y>\dfrac\pi4$ as $\arccos(x)$ is decreasing in $[-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2]$

$\implies?>2y>\dfrac\pi2$

But $-\dfrac\pi2\le u=\arcsin(\sin2y)\le\dfrac\pi2$

So,$u=\pi-2y$ for the above range of $y$

Comment: I did not understand this...

Comment: @JShelly, please pinpoint the confusion

Comment: the 2nd line "actually implies...."

Comment: @JShelly,  If $x<\dfrac1{\sqrt2},\cos^{-1}x=\arccos(x)>\dfrac\pi4$ right?

Comment: yes, you're right