# Why are there conditions for $\sin^{-1} ({x\sqrt{1-y^2} +y\sqrt{1-x^2}})$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

For the addition of inverse trigonometric functions, $\sin^{-1} x+\sin^{-1} y = \sin^{-1} ({x\sqrt{1-y^2} +y\sqrt{1-x^2}})$

But for $\sin^{-1} ({x\sqrt{1-y^2} +y\sqrt{1-x^2}}) = \left\{\begin{matrix} \sin^{-1} x +\sin^{-1} y, \text{ if } -1\leq x,y<1 \text{ and } x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \text{ or, if } xy<0 \text{ and } x^2+y^2 > 1 \\ \pi -(\sin^{-1} x +\sin^{-1} y), \text{ if } 0<x,y\leq 1 \text{ and } x^2 +y^2 >1 \\ -\pi-(\sin^{-1} x + \sin^{-1} y), \text{ if } -1\leq x,y<0 \text{ and } x^2+y^2 > 1 \end{matrix}\right.$

Now what I don't understand is that, **" Where did the conditions come from?"**. *Is there proof or anything for the conditions?* Please explain.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: @labbhattacharjee yeah well this is the inverse of that post. Still might help if I get answers.

Comment: The point is that $-\pi/2\le \sin^{-1} t\le\pi/2$, but $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y$ may lie outside that interval.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know you have to $\pi -$ cuz it may lie out of the interval. But how would know like if $xy \leq 1$ you have to do as follows? How do you get that specific condition?