# (EDITED) Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n } \frac{2^n}{(n+1)\cdot 3^{2n+1}} =\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a series which I have shown converges with the ratio test. I've observed that the partial sums appear to be approaching $\frac{1}{2}$.

How would I go about proving this?  I have considered using the Squeeze theorem, but I can't find any information on using that theorem to show convergence to a specific limit, and I currently have some misgivings that it is rigorous.

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: The series of interest is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n } \frac{2^n}{(n+1)\cdot 3^{2n+1}}$$

Comment: Showing that a series converges is generally far simpler than showing what the limit is.  It is impossible to say how you'd go about doing that without seeing what the series is.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283553/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n22nn2-2n-1) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329518/maclaurin-expansion-of-arccos1-2x2) question?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I had not! Thank you very much for the response, I can show the convergence now.  I sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: When providing clarification, please click on the tiny `edit` to improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Thank you very much for your suggestion, I've made that edit.  I appreciate the feedback as I am obviously new.   Where my question has been answered in the comment thread(or more specifically, in a link to another question), how would you recommend I close this question?

Comment: Please see [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559) about answered-in-comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n } \frac{2^n}{(n+1)\cdot 3^{2n+1}}=\frac 13\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n } \frac{x^n}{(n+1)}$$ where $x=\frac 29$ that is to say
$$S=\frac 1{3x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n } \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}$$ 
$$T=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n } \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)}\implies T'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n \choose n }x^n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}$$ 
$$T=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}=-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 x}+C$$ and $$C=\lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x}}=\frac 12$$ All of the above make
$$S=\frac 1{3x}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 x} }2=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 x} }{6x}$$ Now, make $x=\frac 29$.

Comment: Any denominator of the form an+b can be done like this.

Comment: @martycohen. Be surprised ! I fully agree with you (joke !). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much for your answer.  The only part that I am a bit fuzzy on is how you found the value of $C$.  Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Shaun. Make $x=0$ ! You are  welcome !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you for your response, but I'm afraid I still don't understand; allow me to clarify: why do we choose to set C to be the limit of (1/2)T', and why do we choose x=0 instead of some other term, such at pi or infinity?  I apologize for my lack of understanding, my exposure to analysis this far has been a bit limited.