# Is there any simpler way to find $\sin 2 y$ from $\cos(x+y)=\tfrac13$ and $\cos(x-y)=\tfrac15$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any simpler way to find $\sin 2 y$ from $\cos(x+y)=\tfrac13$ and $\cos(x-y)=\tfrac15$?  Note: $x$ and $y$ are obtuse angles.

My attempt that is not simple is as follows.

Expand both known constraints, so we have

\begin{align}
\cos x \cos y &=4/15\\
\sin x \sin y &=-1/15
\end{align}

Eliminate $x$ using $\sin^2 x +\cos^ 2 x=1$, we have

$$
225 \sin^4 y -210 \sin^2 y +1=0
$$

with its solution 
$\sin^2 y = \frac{7\pm4\sqrt3}{15}$.

Then, $\cos^2 y = \frac{4(2\mp\sqrt3)}{15}$.

\begin{align}
\sin^2(2y) &= 4\cos^2 y\sin^2 y\\
&= 4 \times \frac{4(2\mp\sqrt3)}{15}\times \frac{7\pm4\sqrt3}{15} \\
\sin 2 y & = - \frac{4}{15}\sqrt{(2\mp\sqrt3)(7\pm4\sqrt3)} 
\end{align}

$\sin 2y$ must be negative.

## Edit

Thank you for your effort to answer my question. However, the existing answers seem to be more complicated than my attempt above.

By the way, I am confused in deciding which the correct pair among $(2\mp\sqrt3)(7\pm4\sqrt3)$ is.

Comment: Do you assume x and y are obtuse, or it is specified in the problem?

Comment: @Quanto: Given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $90<x,y<180$ and $\cos(x+y)>0$

$$270<x+y<360\implies\sin(x+y)=-\sqrt{1-(1/3)^2}$$

Again, $-90<x-y<90^\circ\implies\sin(x-y)=\pm\sqrt{1-(1/5)^2}$

Finally $$\sin2y=\sin(x+y+(x-y))=?$$

Comment: I love this approach!

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve the first equation for $x$ and plug this in the second equation .
I got this for $y$:
$$\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=2
   y+\cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You might note that $7+4\sqrt3=(2+\sqrt3)^2$ and $2(2+\sqrt3)=(1+\sqrt3)^2$, and that your $\cos^2y$ has opposite sign to $\sin^2y$.

Answer (score 1):

$90<x,y<180^\circ$

$180<x+y<360\implies x+y=360-\arccos(1/3)$

If $x-y>0,x-y=\arccos(1/5)$

$\sin2y=\sin(360-\arccos(1/3)-\arccos(1/5))=-\sin(\arccos(1/3)+\arccos(1/5))$

Now $\arccos(1/3)+\arccos(1/5)=\arcsin(2\sqrt2/3)+\arccos(2\sqrt6/5)$

Use   [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y)