# Trigonometric Substitutions: When to substitute what?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

There are two similar questions in NCERT Mathematics class 12th book, about Trigonometric inverses but with different domains.

[image]

First part of the question asks, show that

$$\sin^{-1} (2x \sqrt{1 - x^2}) = 2\sin^{-1}(x)$$

For  $-\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \le x\le \frac1 {\sqrt{2}}$. The solution given substitutes $\sin \theta = x$.

The next part has the same $\text{LHS}$ but has $2\cos^{-1}(x)$ in the $\text{RHS}$ for $\frac1{\sqrt2}\le x\le1$. The solution given substitutes $\cos\theta=x$.

My question is, How do I know when I can substitute what in questions like this?
Can't I substitute cos theta and sin theta both for x as given domain is a subset of domain of cos and sin which is $[-1,1]$?

Thank you.

Comment: To display mathematical expressions in proper form, enclose the symbols in pairs of the $ symbol, for a start.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: Please help. Thank you