# Determine the nature of the following series : $\sum \arcsin\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$U_n =  \arcsin\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\right)$$

I have to determine if this series( $\sum U_n$ ) is converging or not.

I’ve tried to know if $\sum \sin(Un)$ is converging and given that $ \sin( U_n) \sim U_n $ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $U_n \geq 0 $ to know if it converges but it didn't work out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use that

$$\arcsin x + \arcsin y  =
\arcsin( x\sqrt{1-y^2} + y\sqrt{1-x^2}) $$

to prove that

$$ \arcsin\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\right)\sim \frac1{\sqrt 3 n}$$

the series diverges by limit comparison test $\sum \frac1n$.

Refer also to

- [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/672575/505767)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\arcsin\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\right)}{1/n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$$
Since harmonic series diverges, by [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), so does $\sum \left(\arcsin\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\right)\right)$.

NB: To justify this test we also need to show that the terms are positive. But I left this to you. ( You may use monotonicity of $\arcsin$, for example).

Comment: We can’t use $\arcsin x\sim x$ in this case since x is not small.

Comment: In that way is really uncorrect, we should use $$\arcsin\left(\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\right)=\arcsin\left(\frac12+\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}\right)$$ and then expand.

Comment: @user how about that? I deleted the addendum