# Find derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$, given $y(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{5\sin x+4\cos x}{\sqrt{41}}\right)$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ if $y=\sin^{-1}\bigg[\dfrac{5\sin x+4\cos x}{\sqrt{41}}\bigg]$

**My Attempt**

Put $\cos\theta=5/\sqrt{41}\implies\sin\theta=4/\sqrt{41}$
$$
y=\sin^{-1}\big[\sin(x+\theta)\big]\implies\sin y=\sin(x+\theta)\\
y=n\pi+(-1)^n(x+\theta)\\
\boxed{\frac{dy}{dx}=(-1)^n}
$$

But my reference gives the solution $y'=1$, am I missing something here ?

Comment: Your solution is incorrect because of the $n\pi$. $y$ from its definition can only be in the range of values $\Bigr[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr]$ because of the range of arcsin

Comment: @NinadMunshi But the sin function can have any domain. So $x+\theta$ need not have to be in the range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

Comment: @NinadMunshi $y=\sin^{-1}\big[\sin(x+\theta)\big]=x+\theta$ iff $x+\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, right? but it is not specified, thats why I had to follow the remaining steps.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out we have

$$y = \arcsin\left[\sin\left(x +\theta\right) \right],$$
where $\theta = \arcsin\frac4{\sqrt{41}}$.

Now observe that ($k\in \Bbb Z$)
$$
\arcsin\sin \alpha = \begin{cases}\alpha-2k\pi & \left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}2\leq \alpha < 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2\right)\\
- \alpha - (2k-1)\pi & \left(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2\leq \alpha < 2k\pi+\frac{3\pi}2\right).\end{cases}
$$

Thus your function is the *triangular wave* (see Figure below)

$$
y = 
\begin{cases}
x +\theta- 2k \pi & \left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}2-\theta\leq x < 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)\\
-x-\theta-(2k-1)\pi-\theta & \left(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2-\theta\leq x< 2k\pi+\frac{3\pi}2-\theta\right)
\end{cases}
$$

whose derivative is

$$
y = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}2-\theta< x < 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)\\
-1 & \left(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2-\theta< x<2 k\pi+\frac{3\pi}2-\theta\right)
\end{cases}
$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your reference is wrong.

$y'=1$ is true half the time -
the other half $y'=-1$
as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting,

$$\sin y=\dfrac{5\sin x+4\cos x}{\sqrt{41}}=\sin(x+\theta)\tag 1$$

with $\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac4{5}$ and recognize $y\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, hence $\cos y \ge 0$,

$$\cos y= \text{sgn}[\cos(x+\theta) ]\cos(x+\theta) $$

Take the derivative of (1),

$$\> y' = \dfrac{\cos(x+\theta)}{\cos y} 
= \dfrac{\cos(x+\theta)}{\text{sgn}[\cos(x+\theta) ]\cos(x+\theta)} \\
=\text{sgn}[\cos(x+\theta) ]=
\begin{cases}
1, & x+\theta -2k\pi \in \left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right]\\
-1, & x+\theta -2k\pi\in \left(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{3\pi}2\right]
\end{cases}
$$

which, as seen in the graph below, alternates at either -1 or 1 depending on the value of $x$.

[image]