# Any hints on how to simplify this $\arcsin(x) + \arcsin(\cos(\arcsin(x)))$ to a single term?

Tags: trigonometry

$\arcsin(x) + \arcsin(\cos(\arcsin(x)))$

Completely stupefied about where to start, if I'm being honest.

Comment: for $-\frac {\pi}2 \le \theta \le \frac {\pi}2$, $\sin \theta = \cos(\theta-\frac \pi 2)$

Comment: Isn't that for any $\theta$ @fleablood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $-1 \le x \le 1$ then $\arcsin x$ is going to be interpreted as being an angle $\arcsin x=\theta$ between $-\frac \pi2\le \theta \le \frac \pi 2$.

If $x\ge 0$ then $\theta \ge 0$ and $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are both $\ge 0$ and $\cos \theta = \sin (\frac \pi 2- \theta)$

If $x < 0$ then $-\frac \pi 2\le \theta \le 0$ and $\sin \theta \le 0$ and $\cos \theta \ge 0$ and $\cos \theta =\sin (\frac \pi 2 + \theta)$.

In either case $\cos \theta \ge 0$ and $\arcsin (\cos \theta) = \begin{cases}\frac \pi 2-\theta& \theta \ge 0\\\frac \pi 2 + \theta& \theta \le 0\end{cases}$

And $\arcsin(x) + \arcsin(\cos(\arcsin(x)))=\begin{cases}\theta +\frac \pi 2-\theta=\frac \pi 2& \theta \ge 0\\\theta+\frac \pi 2 + \theta=2\theta +\frac \pi 2=2x+\frac \pi 2& \theta \le 0\end{cases}$

Let's double check.

Let $x =\frac 12$.  $\sin \frac \pi 6 = \frac 12$ so $\arcsin \frac 12 = \frac \pi 6$.  $\cos \frac \pi 6=\frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and $\sin \frac \pi 3 = \frac {\sqrt{3}}2$ so $\arcsin(\cos(\arcsin x))= \frac  \pi 3$.  And $\arcsin x + \arcsin(\cos(\arcsin x)) = \frac \pi 6 + \frac \pi 3 =\frac \pi 2$.  That confirms.

Le $x = -\frac 12$. $\sin-\frac \pi 6=-\frac 12$ so $\arcsin -\frac 12=-\frac \pi 6$.  $\cos(-\frac \pi 6) = \frac {\sqrt 3}2$ and so, like above, $\arcsin(\cos(\arcsin x)) =\frac \pi 3$.  And so $\arcsin x + \arcsin(\cos(\arcsin(x))= -\frac \pi 6 +\frac \pi 3 = \frac \pi 6$.  Which $= 2(-\frac \pi 6) + \frac \pi 2$.  That confirms.

Comment: Awesome, and here I was trying to transform it using sin A + sin B sum to product identity by letting A = arcsinx and B = arcsin(cos(arcsin(x))).

Answer (score 2):

Try drawing a triangle.

Alternatively, you can start by use the identity $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$. So $\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{\cos^2(\arcsin(x))}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta=\arcsin x$.

If we assume that $0\le \theta\le\frac\pi 2$, then $\cos\theta=\sin(\frac\pi 2-\theta)$ and:
\begin{aligned}\arcsin x + \arcsin(\cos(\arcsin x))
&= \theta + \arcsin(\cos \theta)\\
&= \theta + \arcsin\Big(\sin\big(\frac\pi 2 - \theta\big)\Big)\\
&= \theta + \big(\frac\pi 2 - \theta\big)\\
&=\frac \pi 2
\end{aligned}

Comment: $\arcsin (\sin (\frac \pi2 - \theta)) \ne \frac \pi 2 - \theta$ if $\frac \pi 2 - \theta$ are not in the third or fourth quadrant.

Comment: If $\theta < 0$ then $\frac \pi 2- \theta > \frac \pi 2$ and $\arcsin(\sin(\frac \pi 2-\theta)) =  \frac \pi 2 - (\frac \pi 2 - \theta) = \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ which can be seen by drawing a right triangle with angle $\theta=\arcsin(x)\Rightarrow \sin\theta=x$. We also have the identity (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/672575/570684)) $$\arcsin(\alpha)+\arcsin(\beta)=\arcsin\left(\alpha\sqrt{1-\beta^2}+\beta\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}\right)$$
which holds for $\alpha^2+\beta^2\leq 1$. Putting the two together, the expression simplifies to
$$\arcsin\left(x|x|+1-x^2\right) $$
We can note that when $x\in[0,1]$, this is $\arcsin(1)=\pi/2$. When $x\in[-1,0)$, it becomes $\arcsin(1-2x^2)$.