# Exercise arcsin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

I have this exercise:
Consider the equation $\arcsin(x)=\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

1)Study according to the values ​​of a and b the existence of solution of the equation

I say, for $x,a,b\in [-1,1]$ I have:

$x=\sin(\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b))=\sin(\arcsin(a))\cos(\arcsin(b))+\cos(\arcsin(a))\sin(\arcsin(b))$

then

$x=a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}$

the other question

draw the family of the point $M(a,b)$ for which the equation has a solution

How to do this ?

Comment: $$|\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)|\le \pi/2$$

Comment: @MarkViola what I do with this ?

Comment: @MarkViola what can do with this ?

Comment: Please see my solution.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't understand the proof can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(a,b)=\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)$.  We assume in our analysis that $0\le a\le 1$ and $0\le b\le 1$.  Analysis for $a$ and $b$ in the other quadrants are left as exercises.

---

We wish to restrict $f(a,b)$ such that $0\le f(a,b)\le \pi/2$.  That is, $f(a,b)=\arcsin(x)$ for some $x\in [0,1]$.

---

First note that the arcsine function increases monotonically.  Hence, $f(a,b)=\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)$ increases in each of its arguments $a$ and $b$.

---

> **ASIDE:  Use of Calculus to Show that $\arcsin(x)$ Increases Monotonically**
>
> One way to see that $f(a,b)$ increases monotonically in $a$ and  $b$ to note  its first partial derivatives given by
>
> $$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\\\\
> \frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial b}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$
>
> are strictly positive.

---

Next, note that $\sin(f(a,b))=a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}$.  Inasmuch as the value of the sine function cannot exceed $1$, the maximum value of $a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is $1$.

It is straightforward to show that the locus of points for which $a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}=1$ is given by the set $\{(a,b)|a^2+b^2=1\}$.

---

> **ASIDE:  Use of Calculus to Find Where $\sin(f(a,b))$ Is a Maximum Value**
>
> As easy way to show that $\sin(f(a,b))=1$ when $a^2+b^2=1$ is to set its first partial derivatives, given by
>
> $$\frac{\partial \sin(f(a,b))}{\partial a}=\sqrt{1-b^2}-\frac{ab}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\\\\
> \frac{\partial \sin(f(a,b))}{\partial b}=\sqrt{1-a^2}-\frac{ab}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$
>   to $0$ and solve the resulting equations.

---

So, we now have found that $\sin(f(a,b))$ has its maximum value on the circle $a^2+b^2=1$ for which $\sin(f(a,b))=1$.  Therefore, $f(a,b)=\pi/2$ on the circle $a^2+b^2=1$.

---

Inasmuch as $f(a,b)$ is increasing in both $a$ and $b$, we find that $f(a,b)>\pi/2$ when $a^2+b^2>1$.  Hence, the solution space is given by 
$$a^2+b^2\le 1$$
for $a\in[0,1]$ and $b\in [0,1]$.

---

Comment: We don't study all this is there an other method ?

Comment: Do you understand that the arcsine is an increasing function (I used calculus, but you can show this another way)? If you know that $a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is restricted to have a maximum value of $1$ (Why?), can you see that the maximum occurs when $a^2+b^2=1$ (Just set $a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}$ to $1$ and turn the crank)?  So when $a^2+b^2=1$, $a\sqrt{1-b^2}+b\sqrt{1-a^2}=1$.  This means that $arcsin(x)$ must be $\pi/2$. And since $\arcsin(a)+\arcsin(b)$ increase in both $a$ and $b$, at any values of $a$ and $b$ outside the circle $a^2+b^2=1$ are not permitted. That's all there is.

Comment: Hi Linda. I've edited to provide a way forward without calculus. I've left sections ("ASIDES") that are for those familiar with calculus, but you can gloss over those. Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: i do an other method I found $ab\leq0$ or $a^2+b^2\leq 1$

Comment: Hi Linda. What was your method? Was this answer useful?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y/674096?noredirect=1#comment7540541_674096