# Why is $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)=\frac2{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

In our text book's(Higher Math 1st Paper-by S U Ahmed) differentiation chapter there is a section about replacing $x$(inside inverse trigonometric function) with trigonometric functions. A example problem was $\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$ and the solution given is;

Let
\begin{align*}
  y &=\sin^{-1}\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\\
    &= \sin^{-1}\left(2\sin \theta \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}\right)\\
&=\sin^{-1}\left(2\sin \theta \cos \theta \right)\\
&=\sin^{-1}(\sin 2\theta )\\
&=2\theta\\
&=2 \sin^{-1}x
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}\left(2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)&=\frac{d}{dx}2 \sin^{-1}x\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align*}
But plotting two functions reveals the differentiation is not actually correct. If we differentiate by parts the answer would be $\frac{2\left(-2x^{2}+1\right)}{\sqrt{1-4x^{2}\left(1-x^{2}\right)}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$

[[image: Plotted is Desmos1]

Now my question is why this solution is wrong?

**My guess:** May be this is because replacing $x$ with $\sin \theta$ changes the range of $x$ from $(-\infty,\infty )$ to $[-1,1]$ and may be it causes some issue.

Comment: Set $y=x$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: Because each of $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\cos\theta$ and $\sin^{-1}(\sin 2\theta)=2\theta$ does not necessarily hold. Take $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{8}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is wrong. The range of x in original equation is [-1,1] to make the thing inside square root positive.

The problem starts when author writes sin^-1(sin(2*theta)) = 2*theta. This is wrong. Read about inverse trigonometry functions. The wrong thing is this is true for only some values of theta. For example, put theta = 60 degrees

Comment: the range of $x$ is $[-0.7071,0.7071]$ as the domain of $\sin\alpha$ is $[-1,1]$ so $2x\sqrt{1-x^}=[-1,1]$

Comment: Let f(x) = 2*x*sqrt(1-x^2). Then x=+-1/sqrt(2) is the point of local maxima where the value of f(x) gets 1 before and after which its value decreases.