# Derivative of $f(x)=\arcsin\left(\cos\sqrt{x}\right)+\arccos\left(\sin\sqrt{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

$f:{\mathbb{R}}^{+}\cup \left\{0\right\}\to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x)=\arcsin\left(\cos\sqrt{x}\right)+\arccos\left(\sin\sqrt{x}\right)$ then what is the derivative of function $f?$

A)$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x}}$

B)$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

c)$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

**Here is my solution:** I found derivative of function is
$$\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\cos\sqrt{x}}\right).$$

But I can not reach the answer that given in question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your process for finding this derivative?

Comment: Seems like you've missed a step in applying chain differentiation rule.

Comment: $f(x)=\pi-2\sqrt{x}$

Comment: How about exploiting $\sin\sqrt{x}=\cos (\sqrt{x}-\frac\pi 2)$ and similar?

Comment: The answer A) is right, but only if $0<x<\pi^2/4$

Comment: @softglance You are asking for help, but when someone suggest you may missed a step you just discard the comment?
You should show your process, as Joshua Wang suggested, so we can help you find your mistake.

Comment: Technically all of the answers are wrong because sometimes it is option A and sometimes it is option B.

Comment: @softglance You posted "@ cosmo5 No I do not miss anything".
He was trying to help you, but apparently you don't make mistakes..., you don't miss anything... Yet, somehow, the derivative you calculated is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shortcut solution:**

$$\arcsin\left(\cos(\sqrt{x})\right)+\arccos\left(\sin(\sqrt{x})\right)
\\=\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\sqrt{x}\right)\right)+\arccos\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\sqrt{x}\right)\right).$$

Using this transformation, the rest is easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir

Answer (score 3):

Applying the chain rule we get:
$\\ f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\cos\sqrt{x})^2}}\cdot (-\sin\sqrt{x})\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\sin\sqrt{x})^2}}\cdot (\cos\sqrt{x})\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot\sqrt{x}}=\\=-\frac{1}{2\cdot\sqrt{x}}\cdot(\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}}{|\sin\sqrt{x}|}+\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{|\cos\sqrt{x}|})$

So the correct answer, as @Bernard Massé was saying, is the first one, but only in the interval $(0,(\frac{\pi}{2})^2)$, where both $\sin\sqrt{x}$ and
$\cos\sqrt{x}$ are positive..

Comment: Yes you are right I think this question is little bit awkward

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\arcsin(\cos\sqrt x)+\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin(\sin\sqrt x)$$

$$=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin(\cos\sqrt x)+\arcsin(-\sin\sqrt x)$$

Using [Proof for the formula of sum of arcsine functions $ \arcsin x + \arcsin y $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y),

$$f(x)=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin\left(\cos\sqrt x|\sin\sqrt x|-\sin\sqrt x|\cos\sqrt x|\right) $$

as here $x=\cos\sqrt x,y=-\sin\sqrt x\implies x^2+y^2=1$

Now  use $|u|=\begin{cases}u&\mbox{if } u>0 \\-u &u\le0\end{cases}$

For example if $\cos\sqrt x,\sin\sqrt x$ have the same sign $\iff n\pi\le\sqrt x\le n\pi+\dfrac\pi2$ where $n$ is any integer

$$f(x)=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin0=?$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot sir