# Doubt regarding the formula for $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y$

Tags: trigonometry

When deducing the formula for $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y$, we eventually obtain an expression
$$\sin(A+B)=x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}=k$$
where $A=\sin^{-1}x$ and $B=\sin^{-1}y$, and then deduce $A+B=\sin^{-1}k$.

But for inverse to exist, $A$ and $B$ both must be within the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, but here $A+B$ is in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$. So how can we take $\sin$ to the other side and write $A+B=\sin^{-1}k$ whence $A+B$ should have been in the range $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Answer (score 1):

Trig function of inverse trig functions and combinations will be automatically taken care as you are dealing with *identities* for arguments b with inverse circular angle function  arguments $ (-\infty,\infty) $ including co-terminal angles.

It is natural to be concerned about the unbounded domain limits  beyond $ (\pm \pi/2).$

The co-terminal angles are readily absorbed.

$$\sin(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y)==x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2} $$
$$\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}==\sin ^{-1}( x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}) $$

are true for all real $ |x|<1|, \;|y|<1 $.

The following 3d plot in WA link neatly fits inside a bounded cube of side 2 units. The entire cube can be shifted up or down by an arbitrary amount.

[ArcSin Range Shifted by 1000 $\pi$ angle units](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28%20arcsin%28x%29%2Barcsin%28y%29%29%2B1000%20%2C%20%28x%2C-1%2C1%29%2C%28y%2C-1%2C1%29)

[Inverse Trig graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%28%20arcsinx%20%2B%20arcsin%20y%29%2C%28x%2C-1%2C1%29%2C%20%28y%2C-1%2C1%29)

Comment: Yes you are right that $\sin(\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}y)=x\sqrt{1-y^2}+y\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but now how can you take $\sin^{-1}$ on both sides?Since $\sin^{-1}x+\sin^{-1}$ are in the range $[-\pi,\pi]$ and not $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: Don't follow what the problem is. We can add or remove a thousand semi revolutions in range for inverse functions.