# Sum of arcsines

Tags: trigonometry

It is known that $$\sin^{−1}x+\sin^{−1}y = \sin^{-1}\left[x\sqrt{1 – y^2} + y\sqrt{1 – x^2}\right] $$ if $x, y ≥ 0$ and $x^2+y^2 ≤ 1.$

I know that the given condition makes sure that $\sin^{−1}x+\sin^{−1}y$ lies in the range $[-\pi/2,\pi/2].$

But I can't figure out how the condition is derived?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your equations. Very hard to read otherwise

Comment: @Utkarsh i can prove the identity but how to prove these conditions - x, y ≥ 0 and x^2+y^2 ≤ 1

Comment: Those are given to you, you don't need to prove them

Comment: @Andrei OP wants to know why does this formula only applicable for $x, y \ge 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y

Comment: @Utkarsh Yes thats my question

Comment: From $sin^{-1}x+sin^{-1}y=sin^{-1} \left[ x\sqrt {1-y^2}+y\sqrt {1-y^2}\right]$, we cannot derive $x,y \ge 0$ and $x^2+y^2 \le 1$. 

One counter example is $x=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ and $y=\frac{-\sqrt 3}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

> It is known that $$\sin^{−1}x+\sin^{−1}y = \sin^{-1}\left[x\sqrt{1 – y^2} + y\sqrt{1 – x^2}\right] \tag1$$ if $x, y ≥ 0 \quad \text{and}\quad x^2+y^2 ≤ 1.\tag2$
>
> But I can't figure out how the condition is derived?

Condition $(2)$ cannot be derived from formula $(1).$ In other words, $$(1)\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies(2),$$ and it is false that the given formula is applicable only under the given condition.

[For example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Carcsin+x%2B%5Carcsin+y+%3D+%5Carcsin%28x%5Csqrt%281+%E2%80%93+y%5E2%29+%2B+y%5Csqrt%281+%E2%80%93+x%5E2%29%29), $(x,y)=(1,-1)$ satisfies $(1)$ but not $(2).$

The answers to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/672575/21813), and the fact that the three cases are disjoint, shows that $$(1)\iff \Big(x^2+y^2 \le 1  \quad\text{or}\quad(x^2+y^2 > 1  \quad\text{and}\quad xy< 0)\Big).$$

Answer (score 0):

Actually the range is not restricted, but can be  unbounded depending on integer value chosen for $k$:

$$\sin^{−1}x+\sin^{−1}y = \sin^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{1 – y^2} + y\sqrt{1 – x^2}\right)+ (-1)^k k \pi $$

Answer (score 0):

By the given conditions you can say *0 ≤ x,y ≤ 1*
Therefore   *0 ≤ arcsinx , arcsiny ≤ π/2* and this implies that *0 ≤ arcsinx + arcsiny ≤ π* . But right side is also arcsin of positive value and that implies it should be between 0 and π//2 .Therefore here you have a contradiction and to avoid it you need to consider the formula *Sinθ = Sin ( π - θ)* when you derive the main result. Therefore the correct formula should be,
*arcsinx + arcsiny =*  the given result or π-the given result.

Comment: Since I use my phone to submit hope you will excuse me for the firmat used