# Sum of Sines with the Same Period

Tags: trigonometry

I was doing some problems and decided to graph $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$. To my surprise, I received another sine/cosine function, with some phase shift and change in amplitude!! To be precise, I used a graphing calculator to determine that $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \sqrt2 \sin(x+(\pi/4))$

I understand that $\cos(x)$ is just a phase shift of $\sin(x)$. But now, I'm really curious about this phenomenon. As I understand, the period of 2 sine functions need to be the same to produce another sine function. I wish to know whether there is a general formula for $A \sin(b(x+c)) + A \sin(b(x+d))$, where $A$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, and $c$ and $d$ can be any real number.  [Edit: Just to clarify, I don't mean arcsin. I meant A multiplied by sin.]

Essentially, I'm asking for a formula when you add 2 sine functions with the same amplitude and period, but not necessarily the same phase shift. Thanks a ton! And see if you can justify your answers.

Comment: $\sin(\theta)+\sin(\phi)=2\sin\left(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2}\right)$

Comment: Or see [Wikipedia on "arbitrary phase shift"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Arbitrary_phase_shift)

Comment: Your question asks for both arcsine and sine identities; you should clarify that in your title. Also, there is a [post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672575/proof-for-the-formula-of-sum-of-arcsine-functions-arcsin-x-arcsin-y) that talks about sums of arcsines.

Comment: Replace the cos with sine and Henry comment to derive the answer.

Comment: Hi, yes, I think so! Thank you everyone for the help! I'll see if I can answer my own question here for the sake of completeness